# Incomplete \ifx: How to use ensuremath in split environment?

Tags: math-mode, macros, environments

I have defined this command

```
\newcommand{\edge}[1]{\ifx&#1&\ensuremath{e}\else\ensuremath{e_{#1}}\fi}
```

I now want to use it inside a formula:

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\edge{1}
\end{split}
\end{equation}
```

This works. However, once I put another Latex expression before `\edge{1}`, I get an "Incomplete \ifx; all text was ignored" error. I am not quite sure, but I suspect the combination of `ensuremath` and `split` to be culprit.

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\exists\edge{s} % Error: Incomplete \ifx; all text was ignored after line...
\end{split}
\end{equation}
```

Can you explain me this behavior and suggest a solution?

Comment: You should probably use a better text than `\ifx&#1&....` expecially since `&` has special meaning in math. The `\ifblank{#1}{true}{false}` from `etoolbox` comes to mind

Comment: At the very least you should group the whole construction, so `\newcommand\edge[1]{{...}}` but safer tests might be better.

Comment: The `\ifblank` seems to solve the problem. In previous documents I had no problems with `&` inside math. In this case, `split` is the problem. split uses it for splitting the lines..

Comment: The problem is `&` not `\ensuremath` but you can delete  `\ensuremath` here it is serving no purpose, as you are necessarily in math otherwise `_` would error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's see what happens. When `split` starts off, TeX must process material based on `\halign`, where `&` has a very special role.

In the first case TeX is at the beginning of a cell, when it enters its “look for `\omit` or `\span` phase. The `\ifx&1&...` test returns false and the true text is skipped over, so no `&` is actually seen.

In the second case, the above phase has already ended and when `\edge` is expanded the `&` tokens *are* seen and the first one ends the cell, leaving the conditional unfinished.

Replace the emptiness test with a safer one.

```
\newcommand{\edge}[1]{%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
    \ensuremath{e}%
  \else
    \ensuremath{e_{#1}}%
  \fi
}
```

(assuming that you really want `\ensuremath`, of course).

Actually, the argument seems optional, so I'd recommend something like

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\edge}{o}{%
  \ensuremath{e\IfValueT{#1}{_{#1}}}%
}
```

and call `\edge` or `\edge[1]`. This requires `\usepackage{xparse}` if you're running LaTeX released before 2020-10-01.